# Assimp Tutorial for LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, assimp

I've looked around the internet for tutorials for Assimp tutorials for LWJGL. The best one I've found is https://learnopengl.com/#!Model-Loading/Model, but it has different bindings than LWJGL.

Edit: I am using the bindings provided with LWJGL. The main issue I am running into is that I cannot figure out how to load textures from a material.

Comment: Are you using the bindings that are provided by LWJGL or a different Assimp binding?

Comment: it seems someone is downvoting every post in this question, We are all 0 because I got upvoted and I both upvoted you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing a port of the very same tutorial to Kotlin [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/learn-OpenGL). The Java counterpart should be quite similar though.

I just got there, at the model loading, using the jvm Assimp porting that has being worked [here](https://github.com/java-graphics/assimp).

If you need `stl`, `obj` or `ply` support, you can already use it. I am working on the `collada` format at the moment.

However, there is also this small sample about using the lwjgl assimp binding [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/master/src/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/assimp/WavefrontObjDemo.java)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for such a late response, but check this resource out!

https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/content/chapter27/chapter27.html

The author just completed a chapter on LWJGL and ASSIMP.  Hope this helps!